# Clicking on pixel for certain process with python

Tags: python, automation, process

Hello I am programming a program to automate mouse presses on a program for certain pixels but I don't want a second program to come in the way with that click, my program is going to look for a green pixel and click it on a certain part of the screen, but if there is another program/image in the way that is green I don't want it to click on that

I just want it to click on the process/program I want it to click on, and not click on the screen
If anyone could give me some tips on this, that would be helpful

Comment: It might be helpful if you add what you have tried till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the focused window (do not click if this is focused) use:

```
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
print(GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow()))
```

Do this on your windows and then do `if` statements to stop clicking on pixels.

But to click on the pixels you can use `win32con` and `win32api`:

```
import win32api, win32con
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    sleep(0.01)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
```

To get the pixels and click on them use `PyAutoGui`

```
import pyautogui
from pyautogui import *

width = 1920
hight = 1080

while WindowIsFocused:
    pic = pyautogui.screenshot()
    for x in range(0, width, 1):
        for y in range(0, hight, 1):
            r, g, b = pic.getpixel((x, y))
            if r == 252:
                if g == 200:
                    if b == 118:
                        click(x,y)
                        print("Clicked")
```

Set `width` and `hight` to your screen resolution and `WindowIsFocused` to True if the window you want is focused. Use an extra function for that (the function should run constantly).

I hope that I could help. For any questions ask me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry im not familiar with keys interacting with programs, but i made a little research and found a library called PyWin32 that should statisfy your need. You can search for its documentation or try your luck by finding videos on this particullar library on youtube.

Anyways, hopefully this helped you getting set in the right direction, and feel free to ask any question

Comment: No problem!! :)